# Is there any methods to launch edited HTML files without saving first in notepad++?

Tags: html, notepad++

I edited an HTML file in notepad++,then I want to see what it looks like in web browsers with the changes.But I won't see the changes unless I save the HTML file first.
In short,I want to view the affected HTML file in browsers,but I don't want to "save" first every time.
Are there some nice guys could help me? Thanks. 
[notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)[html](/questions/tagged/html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot view your changes without saving a file.

HOWEVER, you can use chrome/firefox developer tools that provide you with those features.

Here is a quick video to get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsX6qwQqGgQ

Once you are satisfied with your changes, you can always copy and paste the code from the firebug window.

Comment: I know that [tag:ultraedit] can do this.I think this feature will save  a lot of operations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [plugin](http://chiselapp.com/user/vor0nwe/repository/npp_preview/home) for notepad++, but you have to save the file anyway. I don't think there is a possibility to see changes without saving. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a N++ Plugin but it works pretty nice when I used it a few years ago:

http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/

It's a plugin for Firefox which reloads tabs when a local file is changed.